# order access error after magento and payment module update

Tags: error, backend, payment-methods

I have updated my magento version from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.1.

I changed the mysql BD path to my original Database and it is almost working, except that for some order, when I try to access them in backend, I have got errors.

It seems to be due to the payment method that is not found...
(I have also updated my credit card payment module.)

In the Order tab in backend, all the orders payed by credit card have nothing in the "Payment Method" column...

Here is the error I get :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:46:"The requested Payment Method is not available.";i:1;s:6303:"#0 /homepages/20/d524244365/htdocs/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(119): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(50): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getInfoBlock(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#3 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->setPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#4 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->_beforeToHtml()
#5 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_payment', true)
#7 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(112): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_payment')
#8 xxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getPaymentHtml()
#9 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#10 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 xxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#16 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#17 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#18 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#23 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#25 xxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#26 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#27 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#28 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#33 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#34 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#35 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#36 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#37 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#38 xxx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#39 xxx/index.php(96): Mage::run('fr_store', 'store')
#40 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/24/key/1bd9133e7379c5c75dc23b2a70336d0f/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your payment module has changed its identifier, so the old orders don't know what to reference to. You can fix that by going directly in your database (**try this on a dev copy first, and make a backup before rolling live**):

```
SELECT method FROM `sales_flat_order_payment` WHERE parent_id = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
```

Then when you got the payment method, you can just run:

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order_payment` SET method = 'NEW_METHOD' WHERE method = 'OLD_METHOD';
```